# Convert string to date on an input date inside an angularjs repeater

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a repeater with table row where I have a date, which could be edited. The problem is I can not set the model with string instead of a date object and is not possible to  apply a filter on an date input. Which could be the workaround here?

Thanks

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="item in collection">
    <td data-ng-bind="item.name"></td>
    <td data-ng-bind="item.sharedDate | date:'MMMM dd, yyyy'"></td>
    <td>
        <span data-ng-bind="item.note"></span>
        <textarea data-ng-model="item.note"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span data-ng-bind="item.expiryDate | date:'MMMM dd, yyyy'"></span>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="expiryDate" data-ng-model="(item.expiryDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy')">
    </td>
```

Comment: can it be converted to a `Date` object? e.g. `$scope.yourDateThing = new Date(your date val)`

Comment: The loop is in the view using ngRepeat, the idea was not to have to convert it on the controller. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data-ng-model` is a **2-way data binding** and you can not use an expression. It must reference a scope variable so that `ngModel` can read and write.

If the value of `item.expiryDate` is not in the correct format for `ngModel` then you have to pre-process this in the controller before it's used in the template.

You'll need do something like this first in the controller or directive.

```
_.each($scope.collection,function(item) { item.expiryDate = $filter('date')('MM/dd/yyyy'));
```

Now in your template you can use `ngModel` as a 2-way data binding on that value.

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="expiryDate" data-ng-model="item.expiryDate">
```

Comment: Thanks @Mathew. I wanted to avoid to loop the object on the controller, but seems like is what I have to do.